# Is a recursive function undefined if it doesn't have a base case?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

For example: $f(x) = 2 \times f(x-1)$

Could I say that the function $f(x) = $ undefined ?

If I set $f(0) = 1$ as the base case, then $f(5) = 32$ for example.

Comment: I would say the function is undefined or ill-defined, simply because you can't tell me what its domain is, or what values it takes on. You can't tell me what $f(2)$ is, for instance, without another point to jump off of for the recursion. I guess maybe you could make some weird argument about functions $f : \varnothing \to \varnothing$, but that's probably not important in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Though I do wonder if there are some edge cases where it might be defined. It happens sometimes in the more general functional equations that the nature of the functional equation forces a certain value for some inputs; maybe the same can be true of a narrow class of recursive function definitions?

Comment: You can assume $f(0)=a$ for some constant real $a$ and analyze what you need with $a$ unspecified, and express all your results in terms of $a$ then

Comment: This seems like a semantics issue.  Is $f(n)=k2^n$ undefined?  Since $k$ isn't specified, it's certainly not as defined as we would like, but still.